# Import CSV into existing realm

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is there a way to import a CSV file to an existing realm? I know realm browser can import CSV but it imports it to a new realm copy which I don't want.

I have an idea to create my own converter class, which will read CSV and dump data into existing realm. But please if there is an easier way to do it, do suggest.

Currently, I have an existing realm in my app at the default location.

Comment: I don't think there are any easy ways to import CSV into an _existing_ Realm file. You might want to consider modifying https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter to do what you want.

Comment: I suppose...Thanks for the reply @AustinZ.